# How to compile a own pxelinux.0 file ? or decompile a pxelinux.0?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, ipxe

is any way to custom pxelinux.0 file?

I want boot computer from PXE mode,and the general pxelinux.0 file is not meet my situation，so what should i do to modify pxelinux.0, thanks a lot

Comment: What did you read in iPXE documentation so far?

Comment: @0andriy i find a way that viod compile the pxelinux.0 file to meet my situation,thanks

Comment: pxelinux is not iPXE, did you miss tag the question?